# Sails.js - Have a 'contains' or query in url to fetch appropriate JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

My Sails.js application has a model called 'Ideas' and using the default blueprint REST api, I can access the contents of the collection when I go to: http://example.com/ideas/find

Furthermore, by default, I can also limit the data to get specific titles: http://example.com/ideas/find?title=How to Watch TV

Although what I want to do is display the JSON data of ALL titles that contain the keyword 'T' but when I replace the above with the likes of

```
a) ?title=TV
b) ?q=TV
c) ?query=TV
d) ?where(title : (contains:'TV')
```

none of them work

How can I get JSON output that contains all titles that contains a particular keyword?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Find.html), the where example should work. It uses curly brackets instead of parenthesis though.

`?where={"title":{"contains":"TV"}}`

Comment: actually one more question :-) what would the query be if I want the title to contain TV & Music - I tried the following but they did not do it: a) ideas/find?where={"title":{"contains":"music"}}&{"title":{"contains":"film"}}

Answer (score 0):

For multiple use ",".

**Example :**

```
ideas/find?where={"title":{"contains":"music"}},{"title":{"contains":"film"}}
```